# python efficient way to compare nested lists and append matches to new list

Tags: python

I wish to compare two nested lists. If there is a match between the first element of each sublist, I wish to add the matched element to a new list for further operations. Below is an example and what I've tried so far: 
Example:

```
x = [['item1','somethingelse1'], ['item2', 'somethingelse2']...]
y = [['item1','somethingelse3'], ['item3','somethingelse4']...]
```

What I've I tried so far:

```
match = []
for itemx in x:
    for itemy in y:
        if itemx[0] == itemy[0]:
            match.append(itemx)
```

The above of what I tried did the job of appending the matched item into the new list, but I have two very long nested lists, and what I did above is very slow for operating on very long lists. Are there any more efficient ways to get out the matched item between two nested lists?

Comment: Can there be duplicate first elements in either of the two lists?

Comment: Are the inner lists always pairs?

Comment: @HeapOverflow No there are not always pairs. The example is just a demonstration for what I'm trying do. The original inner list contains four items.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use a data structure with constant-time membership testing. So, using a `set`, for example:

```
seen = set()
for first,_ in x:
    seen.add(first)

matched = []
for first,_ in y:
    if first in seen:
        matched.append(first)
```

Or, more succinctly using set/list comprehensions:

```
seen = {first for first,_ in x}
matched = [first for first,_ in y if first in seen]
```

Answer (score 1):

(This was before the OP changed the question from `append(itemx[0])` to `append(itemx)`...)

```
>>> {a[0] for a in x} & {b[0] for b in y}
{'item1'}
```

Or if the inner lists are always pairs:

```
>>> dict(x).keys() & dict(y)
{'item1'}
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that this will raise an exception if the sublists are not length 2. They happen to be two elements long in the OP, but it's not clear that this wasn't just for the example.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np
y=[l[0] for l in y]
x=np.array(x)
x[np.isin(x[:, 0], y)]
```

Comment: If you have to write `list(map(lambda))`, wouldn't it be better to just use a list comprehension?